# Using CSharp CodeDom for a full property set statement

Tags: c#, properties, codedom

Using CSharp CodeDom, I would like to generate the following code:

```
set
{
    if(_myproperty != value)
    {
        _myproperty = value;
    }
}
```

I can do the following but it is not what I want

```
cmp.SetStatements.Add(
    new CodeConditionStatement(
        //condition
        new CodeBinaryOperatorExpression(
            new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(),"_myproperty" ),
            CodeBinaryOperatorType.ValueEquality,
            new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()),
        //true statements
        new CodeStatement[]{},
        //False Statements
        new CodeStatement[]{
            new CodeAssignStatement(
                new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(),"_myproperty"),
                new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()
            )
        })
);
```

the above will give me

```
set
{
    if(_myproperty == value)
    {
    }
    else
    {
        _myproperty = value;
    }
}
```

Question is: How to perform the '!=' or valueinequality operation using the CodeBinaryOperatorType Enumeration, or can I do this?

I am assuming the IdentityInequality is not what I need. I cannot see it in the documentation

Comment: You're assuming it's not `IdentityInequality` but have you tried it? I'm fairly certain that's what you want. Also: why do you generate false statements when you don't want any?

Comment: Thanks, I actually want to generate the != statement. I included the example using equality to try to clarify my thought process... apologies if I confused you. my end goal is to generate an mvvm viewmodel class with the OnPropertyChanged("mypropertyname") included in the set statements

Comment: I know what you mean but have you tried simply changing `CodeBinaryOperatorType.ValueEquality` to `CodeBinaryOperatorType.IdentityInequality`? A quick look around online tells me that this can be used to get the `!= operator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# doesn't have separate value equality and reference equality operators, only `==`. This means that `IdentityInequality` will work the way you want and produce `!=`.

You can verify this by looking at [the reference source of `CSharpCodeProvider`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/microsoft/csharp/csharpcodeprovider.cs,de8ff90f31a16311).